# How to adjust the font size and set a specific font for the controller name

Tags: ios, swift, controller, title, uidocumentinteractioncontroller

I want to decrease the font size to small and set a specific Arabic font for the controller name.

Thanks in advance.

Preview:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzIlc.png)

Code:

```
if let string = viewModel.base64String {
            
            guard var document = (FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)).last, let convertedData = Data(base64Encoded: string) else{
                print("something went wrong")
                return
            }
            
            document.appendPathComponent("MonthlyStatement.pdf")
            do {
                try convertedData.write(to: document)
            }catch{
                
            }
            
            
            let controller = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: document)
            controller.delegate = self
            controller.name = NSLocalizedString("Monthlystatement", comment: "")
            controller.presentPreview(animated: true)
        } else {
            //print(viewModel.error)
            //self.showAlertViewWithTitle(title:"", message: NSLocalizedString("Record not found", comment: ""))
        }
    }
```

Thanks again.